# How would I accomplish this?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am currently working on a site, and while I am pretty fluent in CSS and HTML I am still new to Javascript and PhP. I am trying to create a form, that the user can input information in and when some values are changed the total $ will change. For example if they choose 3 instead of one the total will multiply by three. Then when they press submit, it links them to a paypal and has the total there also so that they can pay. I enjoy the challenge of figuring this out but just wanted to know the best way to do this. Should I create an inline frame in my html, and then ONLOAD call a javascript function that places the form on the page, and then through a few more javascript functions make it so that the total will change when different values are put in? I am open to all ideas. Right now I have this and I have a feeling that there is an easier way to do it :

HTML

```
<BODY onLoad="javascript:showform()">
<IFRAME class="iframe" src="about:blank" id="formarea" name="formarea">
</IFRAME>
```

javascript

```
function showform() {
    var data = ""
       data +="<div style ='position: relative; margin-right: 50%; padding-left:120px; padding-right:60px;'>"
       data +="<form method='post' name='contact_form' action='contact-form-handler.php'>"
       data +="<fieldset>"
       data +="<legend>Your Details</legend>"
       data +="<ol>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=name>Name</label>"
       data +="<input id=name name=name type=text placeholder='First and last name' required>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=email>Email</label>"
       data +="<input id=email name=email type=email placeholder='example@domain.com' required>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=phone>Phone Number</label>"
       data +="<input id=phone name=phone type=tel placeholder='555-555-5555' required>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="</ol>"
       data +="</fieldset>"
       data +="<fieldset>"
       data +="<legend>Logo Details</legend>"
       data +="<ol>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=logo>Logo #</label>"
       data +="<select name=frontdesign>"
       data +="<option value='1'>1</option>"
       data +="<option value='2'>2</option>"
       data +="<option value='3'>3</option>"
       data +="<option value='4'>4</option>"
       data +="<option value='5'>5</option>"
       data +="<option value='6'>6</option>"
       data +="</select>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=nameofT>Name of Tournament</label>"
       data +="<input id=nameofT name=nameofT type=text placeholder='Los Angeles Tournament 2013' required>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=colors>Color(s)</label>"
       data +="<input id=colors name=colors type=text placeholder='Kelly Green, Navy Blue' required>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="</ol>"
       data +="</fieldset>"
       data +="<fieldset>"
       data +="<legend>Shirt Details</legend>"
       data +="<ol>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=small>Small</label>"
       data +="<textarea id=small name=small rows=1 type=text placeholder='#' required></textarea>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=medium>Medium</label>"
       data +="<textarea id=medium name=medium rows=1 type=text placeholder='#' required></textarea>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=large>Large</label>"
       data +="<textarea id=large name=large rows=1 type=text placeholder='#' required></textarea>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=xlarge>X-Large</label>"
       data +="<textarea id=xlarge name=xlarge rows=1 type=text placeholder='#' required></textarea>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=xxlarge>XX-Large(If more then 3, add $1.50 per shirt)</label>"
       data +="<textarea id=xxlarge name=xxlarge rows=1 type=text placeholder='#' required></textarea>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="</ol>"
       data +="</fieldset>"
       data +="<fieldset>"
       data +="<legend>Add Ons</legend>"
       data +="<ol>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=colorofshirt>Color of Shirt (If not White)</label>"
       data +="<input id=colorofshirt name=colorofshirt type=text placeholder='Kelly Green, Navy Blue' required >"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="<li>"
       data +="<label for=printonback>Print on Back</label>"
       data +="<input id=printonback name=printonback type=text placeholder='2013 Champions' required>"
       data +="</li>"
       data +="<br>"
       data +="</ol>"
       data +="</fieldset>"     
       data +="<fieldset>"
       data +="<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
       data +="</fieldset>"
       data +="</form>"
       data +="</div>"
       formarea.document.writeln(data)
    }// JavaScript Document
```

I have not even began figuring out the $total part. From a professionals point of view, what would be the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: That whole form is static. No reason to make it a bunch of JS. Write it as normal HTML, exactly where you want it, but hide it using CSS. `display:none` will hide it till you need it. Use JS to change the CSS to `display:block` when you want it to be visible. Do you even need the iFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example of how to do this using JQuery and can also be tested on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShqyS/)

```
<script>
    $('#quantity').change(function(){
        calcTotal();
    });
    $('#price').change(function(){
        calcTotal();
    });

    function calcTotal(){
        var q = $('#quantity').val();
        var p = $('#price').val();
        $('#total').val(q * p);
    }
</script>

<div>
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <input type="text" id="price" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" id="quantity" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="total">Total</label>
    <input type="text" id="total" />   
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. I like your method its simple. However I am a complete rookie at javascript and even more so at jquery. I see how this works in JSFIDDLE but when I put it into my page it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: You have to include the JQuery library in the header of your page.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is not recommended because iframes should be avoided whenever possible, and you shouldn't use Javascript to store and insert HTML in that way.

Render your form in HTML and use `.show()` and `.hide()` to show/hide the form.

Second, write some javascript that watches for `.change` events and does your calculations for you.

For example (this is jQuery, not pure javascript):

```
$(#number_field).on('change', function(){
  # calculate...
})
```

Comment: This is jquery not pure javascript, you should've mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

First, you must use

```
var data = ["long string",
 "another long string",
 "another long string"].join("");
```

its faster than `data += "long striiiiiiing"`

Second...you can get the value using `onchange` for list item. Once an ordered list's value was change, it will trigger an event.

third, when using attributes, the proper syntax is attribute="value" not attribute=value
like in this code

```
input id=email name=email type=email
```

it must be

```
input id='email' name='email' type='email '
```

Answer (score 0):

Never add HTML tags like that (as in the whole part). Use it to add tags dynamically but in small parts.

Using the `onchange` or `oninput` or `onfocus` or `onsubmit` to handle form elements is best approach.

For example,

```
 <input type="text" name="txt" value="Hello" onchange="checkField(this.value)">
 <scrript>
 function checkField(val)
 {
   alert("The input value changed to: " + val);
  }
 </script>
```